# Win32 Listview fully show items by default

Tags: listview, winapi

Can anybody please tell me how to make Win32 ListView items fully show by default?

Currently my ListView items only partly show when they are not activated.

No item selected

[image: Img1]

First item selected

[image: Img2]

Is there possibly a ListView (Extended) Style to do this?

The solution might also fix the issue that the selected item is drawn partly over/behind the other one.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the result I wanted by using custom item drawing (NM_CUSTOMDRAW & CDDS_ITEMPREPAINT).

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bzShz.png)